# Django route all non-catched urls to included urls.py

Tags: python, django, url-routing

I want every url that does not start with 'api' to use the foo/urls.py

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from foo import urls as foo_urls

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^api/', include('api.urls', namespace='api')),
url(r'^.*/$', include(foo_urls)),
]
```

foo/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from foo import views

urlpatterns = [
url(r'a$', views.a),
]
```

This does not work, any idea ?

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work? What URL are you testing and what is the result?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want a catch all url pattern, use:

```
url(r'^', include(foo_urls)),
```

From [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs):

> Whenever Django encounters `include()` it chops off whatever part of the URL matched up to that point and sends the remaining string to the included URLconf for further processing.

In your current code, the regex `^.*/$` matches the entire url `/a/`. This means that there is nothing remaining to pass to `foo_urls`.

Comment: You don't need the `^` you can just do `url('', include(foo_urls)),`

Comment: @Boris yes, `url(r'^', include(...))` and `url('', include(...))` will behave the same in this case, but in general, the `^` does make a difference. For example `url('blog/', include(...))` will match `weblog/` but `url(r'^blog/', include(...))` will not. If you're using `url()` or `re_path`, then I'd recommend using `r'^'` for consistency. The easiest solution might be to switch to `path()` and use `path('', include(...))`.

Answer (score 3):

do this:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^api/', include('api.urls', namespace='api')),
url(r'^', include(foo_urls)),
]
```